# Was following a tut on pygame sprites and got some errors, not sure whats wrong with my code it says line 462 has an error, there is no line 462

Tags: python, pygame, sprite

This is my code. If you respond please include full code, i am bad at replacing things.

```
import pygame

white = (255,255,255)
black = (0,0,0)
orange = (255,165,0) 



pygame.init()

class Will(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
def __init__(self,width,height, pos_y,pos_x,color):
    super().__init__()
    self.image = pygame.Surface([width,height])
    self.image.fill(black)
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect() 
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    display = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
    pygame.display.set_caption('Slap Chris Rock!')

    will = Will(50,50,100,100,(black))
    will_group = pygame.sprite.Group()
    will_group.add(Will)

    exit = False

    while not exit:

for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        exit = True
    # print(event)

display.fill(white)      
pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
quit()

will_group.draw(display)
```

please note these are the actual indentations. my last post had wrong indentations, i have fixed that.

Comment: Show us the *full traceback*, not just the error message. That contains the information we need to solve the problem. I understand that it seems to you to be just meaningless gibberish . But it isn't. Part of learning to code is learning to make sense of the error messages you get.

Comment: There is an error on line 12 anyway - you haven't indented the code for the class.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't include the full code so i can't be 100% sure, but from what i tested, the solution is pretty simple, you just have to replace the
`will_group.add(Will)` by `will_group.add(will)` with a non caped "will". What your code does is that it tries to add the class Will to a group, and not the instance of Will named will. Try avoiding similar names and you will have less errors like this one.

Edit: in fact the whole code was there, but the indentation is messed up. Here is the working code:

```
import pygame

white = (255,255,255)
black = (0,0,0)
orange = (255,165,0) 



pygame.init()

class Will(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,width,height, pos_y,pos_x,color):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface([width,height])
        self.image.fill(black)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect() 
        clock = pygame.time.Clock()
display = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
pygame.display.set_caption('Slap Chris Rock!')

will = Will(50,50,100,100,(black))
will_group = pygame.sprite.Group()
will_group.add(will)

exit = False

while not exit:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            exit = True
        # print(event)

    display.fill(white)      
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
quit()

will_group.draw(display)
```